# Laravel use Trait methods in another Trait

Tags: php, traits

Normally I have a question about something not working, now I have a question about something that IS working, I am just confused as to why. This is the structure that I have in Laravel:

**ExampleController**

```
use App\Http\Traits\Trait1;
use App\Http\Traits\Trait2;

ExampleController extends Controller {

   use Trait1, Trait2;

   public function index()
   {
      // I can use methods from Trait1 and Trait2 here, works fine
   }

}
```

**Trait1**

```
namespace App\Http\Traits;

trait Trait1 {
   exampleMethodTrait1()
   {
   }
}
```

**Trait2**

```
namespace App\Http\Traits;

trait Trait2 {

   $test = $this->exampleMethodTrait1();

}
```

Calling a method defined in Trait1 from Trait2 actually works, while I have not added `use App\Http\Traits\Trait1;` in Trait2. Is that because they are both loaded in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are both loaded in your controller as a part of it therefore they have access between them also controller methods

See the example 4

```
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Okay, Let me put same code and explain you why it is working.

**Trait1**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Traits;

trait Trait1 {
   public function exampleMethodTrait1()
   {
       echo 'okay';
   }
}
?>
```

**Trait 2**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Traits;

trait Trait2 {
    public function bar() {
        var_dump(get_class($this));
        $test = $this->exampleMethodTrait1();
    }
}
?>
```

**MyController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Traits\Trait1;
use App\Http\Traits\Trait2;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    use Trait1, Trait2;


    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->bar();
    }
}
```

Now, if you will notice in Trait 2, `var_dump(get_class($this));` $this is instance of MyController and not instance of trait 2, that is how it is working and it is expected behavior.

Now if you want to know if you can use one trait in side another

**YES**

You can do like
**TaraitA**

```
Trait A {
}
```

**TraitB**

```
Trait B {
    use A;
}
```

And it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm still confused as to why I would do `use A` in Trait B when the method from Trait A is already available in Trait B.

Comment: @eskimo okay, why you are thinking it is available in another trait, it is available is the class, the execution starts from class and you are accessing each of them with class instance, in case of trait A, trait B, you will not use both in any class, you will use the child trait in class.

Comment: This is what my question is about; how come can I access a method from trait1 in trait2? I understand I can access them in the class in the controller because I load them there.

Comment: @eskimo Why you are thinking you are calling the function inside the trait, while you are actually calling it inside the class.

Comment: Because I am :-). Please read my original question again. There you see that I am calling a function in trait2 that was defined in trait1. But I am not loading trait1 into trait2.

Comment: @eskimo I have read your question, see, how it is getting executed, if you are thinking you are accessing it from another trait can you create an instance of that trait? If not can you try making the function static and access that using trait name? If not how you are thinking you are calling it from trait?

Comment: I am calling `$this->exampleMethodTrait1()`, which is a method from Trait1, within Trait2. Without putting `use Trait1;` in Trait2.

Comment: @eskimo you don’t need to, because now it is behaving like nonstatic method of class, after using it in class.

Comment: `Trait1` & `Trait2` are at the same level, even if you put them one inside the other. `$this` is a reference to the instance of the class where you use the traits.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion comes from believing that the `$this` inside a trait corresponds to the trait itself. But it is not.

**Traits are nothing by themselves:** they exists only in the context of a real class, as a helper to *copy-paste* methods around but not visually polluting your actual classes.

The `$this` you use to call `exampleMethodTrait1` is **not** an instance of `Trait2` (nor `Trait1`) but an instance of `ExampleController`, that has copied the methods over from the traits.

This doesn't happen only with traits, though, but also with parent classes in the hierarchy:

*Example*

```
abstract class Base {}            // First level of inheritance
class Building extends Base {}    // Second level of inheritance
class House extends Building {}   // Last level of inheritance
```

- `$this` (and `static`) always corresponds to an instance of the most concrete class of the hierarchy (the last level of inheritance).
- `self` instead refers to the actual `class` instance (the same level of inheritance where the method is defined). Still never a `trait`, they cannot be instantiated by themselves.
- the traits are not part of the hierarchy, but blindly pasted where you `use` them.